# How create WHERE clause for a table which can be filtered for three connected parameters?

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net

I have a table in MySQL DB which has the following structure:

ID | PRODUCT | PRICE | **SHOP** | **POS** | **SELLER**

I need to make a function which will allow to filter that mysql table from my Front-End by **SHOP**, **POS** and **SELLER**.

Each **POS** belong to a **SHOP** and Each **SELLER** belong to a **POS**

In my FrontEnd i have a Three View which shows the **SHOPS** > **POS** > **SELLERS** and Each can be checked or uncheked, then i send the checked data to my back-end.

Here i was going to create a WHERE clause like `WHERE ("SHOP_TB, POS_TB, SELLER_TB) IN ((0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1))`

Which will select the data from **SHOP** 0 from **POS** 0 and from **SELLERS** 0 and 1

The issue is that some POS could not have **SELLERS** so i have to select whole data from it...

How can i manage to do it?

And is it a good practise doing long WHEREs like this? (The example is very small real data can have up to **20 SHOPS** which has up to **10 POS** in it and up to **30 SELLERS** so the WHERE will become very large)

My code for now looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function QueryParametri(configs As List(Of ModelConfig), table As String) As String
    If configs.Count > 0 Then
        Dim WhereOperatori As String = "(NPV_" & table & ", NCASSA_" & table & "" & ", OPERATORE_" & table & ") IN ("
        Dim WhereINOperatori As String = ""
        Dim WhereCasse As String = "(NPV_" & table & ", NCASSA_" & table & ") IN ("
        Dim WhereINCasse As String = ""
        For Each config As ModelConfig In configs
            For Each cassa As ListCasse In config.casse
                If cassa.operatori.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each operatore As ListOperatori In cassa.operatori
                        WhereINOperatori &= "(" & config.NPV & ", " & cassa.CS & ", " & operatore.OP & "), "
                    Next
                Else
                    WhereINCasse &= "(" & config.NPV & ", " & cassa.CS & "), "
                End If
            Next
        Next
        WhereINOperatori = Mid(WhereINOperatori, 1, WhereINOperatori.Length - 2)
        WhereOperatori = WhereOperatori & WhereINOperatori & ")"
        If (WhereINCasse IsNot "") Then
            WhereINCasse = Mid(WhereINCasse, 1, WhereINCasse.Length - 2)
            WhereCasse = WhereCasse & WhereINCasse & ")"
            WhereOperatori &= " AND " & WhereCasse
        End If
        Return WhereOperatori
    End If

    Return ""
End Function
```

But it fails as the query need both **SHOP**, **POS** and **SELLER** but if the POS has no SELLERS the query will fail...

I'd accept solutions even in c# as i have no problem with it.

**EDIT:**

I've changed my code to split the WHERE for the one with SELLERS and one without,

The where become:

```
WHERE (NPV_SC, NCASSA_SC, OPERATORE_SC) IN ((0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 1, 6), (0, 1, 7), (0, 1, 8), (0, 1, 9), (0, 1, 10), (0, 1, 11), (0, 1, 12), (0, 1, 13), (0, 1, 14), (0, 1, 15), (0, 1, 16), (0, 1, 21), (0, 1, 23), (0, 1, 25), (0, 1, 27), (0, 1, 30), (0, 1, 108), (0, 1, 110), (0, 1, 111), (0, 1, 999), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 5, 0), (0, 5, 1), (0, 5, 3), (0, 5, 4), (0, 5, 6), (0, 5, 7), (0, 5, 8), (0, 5, 9), (0, 5, 10), (0, 5, 11), (0, 5, 12), (0, 5, 13), (0, 5, 14), (0, 5, 15), (0, 5, 16), (0, 5, 21), (0, 5, 23), (0, 5, 25), (0, 5, 27), (0, 5, 30), (0, 5, 108), (0, 5, 110), (0, 5, 111), (0, 5, 999), (0, 5, 1), (0, 5, 2), (4, 1, 0), (4, 1, 1), (4, 1, 12), (4, 1, 22), (4, 1, 23), (10, 1, 0), (10, 1, 1), (10, 1, 2), (10, 1, 5), (10, 1, 10), (10, 1, 11)) AND (NPV_SC, NCASSA_SC) IN ((1, 1))
```

But the issue is that cause of that `AND (NPV_SC, NCASSA_SC) IN ((1, 1))` no data is shown while if i remove it i will be able to see my data, but i need that part of query as it will have to return all the data of SHOP 1 POS 1 which has no SELLERS

UI:

[image]

This is the sidebar while on the main screen i have different data like statistics for sold items and other stuff.

Comment: Consider using some ORM for this purpose. There is a potential for SQL injection attack when creating SQL commands like this

Comment: @TomasChabada i would but i can't as that code was yet used for SHOP / POS filtering and i've needed to add the SELLERS one, the boss said that the filtering has to be made ASAP without loosing more time on it

Comment: If you want to build WHERE clause depends on the value for a column is provided or not then use `WHERE 1=1` as a stub and connect your conditions to it. For example, if filter value for column `field1` is provided then you join the condition to a stub obtaining `WHERE 1=1 AND field1 = {value}`, if the filter value is not provided then you simply skip the addition of `field1` condition. Anycase you obtain correct WHERE clause, even when none filtering values are prtovided.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the UI and better explain what exactly it is searching? It is hard to understand exactly what you want

Comment: @CaiusJard just added the UI, it is searching for data about the SHOP | POS | SELLER and show all statistic data about sells and other stuff but the user can choose to see that data only for a specific POS that is in a SHOP (inluding all SELLERS) or just data for a singler SELLER that belong to a POS which belong to a SHOP

Comment: And are there multiple SELLERs in every POS and multiple POS in every SHOP and multiple SHOPs in this UI?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes there are multiple SHOP > MULTIPLE POS IN SHOP > MULTIPLE SELLERS IN POS

Comment: Are you able to give us a picture of the DB schema for these 3 tables?  Off the info so far, seems like a pretty standard relational hierarchy structure which could probably be handled with a properly structured sql query rather than all these loops your leaping through to build the where

Comment: @Hursey there is no relations tables it's just one table with data that contains columns with infos data like "PRODUCT DESCRIPTION" "SOLD PRICE" "CATEGORY" "SHOP" "POS" "SELLER"